# Creating custom environment with ruled caption

Tags: listings, captions, environments, minted

I'm trying to create an environment for listing code that will use a ruled caption (in the style of the `algorithm` package). I **don't** want it to be a float environment, since I have to allow pagebreaks for long chunks of code.

```
\usepackage{minted, caption}
% other code
\newenvironment{code}{\captionsetup{type=listing}}{}
```

I tried `\captionsetup[ruled]{type=listing}`, but I'm getting the message

`Package caption error: \caption outside float`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `\captionof{listing}`?

Comment: If I read the manual correctly, \captionsetup[ruled]{} doesn't add a rule to caption, but rather formats the caption for a ruled float.

Answer (score 1):

The caption package tests for all sorts of things, including the counter name, the environment name, \l@listing, \ext@listing and Knuth knows what else.  Frankly, it is a whole lot easier just to use the float package to create a listing float type and redefine the listing environment to NOT generate a float.

Minted doesn't work on my system, so I wasn't able to test it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\newfloat{listing}{htp}{lol}
\floatname{listing}{Listing}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{listing}{\def\@captype{listing}%
  \trivlist
  \vskip\intextsep\item}%
{\par\vskip\intextsep\endtrivlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{listing}
\hrule
\caption{test}
\hrule
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```